# How can I use find( ) to search for a specific matching Element but have it display an alternate element inside that same object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, find

I really hope i used element and object correctly in the title. My apologies ahead of time if i defined them incorrectly. I struggle with that. So the array given to me looks like this

```
const drinkOrders = [
  { id: 0, customerName: 'Zachary', drinkName: 'Dirty Martini'},
  { id: 1, customerName: 'Juan', drinkName: 'Zombie'},
  { id: 2, customerName: 'Kayla', drinkName: 'Mojito'},
  { id: 3, customerName: 'Zachary', drinkName: 'Mojito'}
]
```

I am being asked to use find() to find the one that has an id of 3 and then only print the customerName of that property. Ive been trying well over an hour and did some research and utilized the resources that were given to me and still cant come up with the answer. any ideas on how i might go about solving this?

i tried

```
console.log(drinksOrders.find((drinkorders) => drinkorders.id === 3);
```

I am told to print the customersName of id: 3.

Comment: Please note that `drinksOrders` is not the same as `drinkOrders`. If you change that, the code works

Comment: you have a type `drinksOrders` . just `console.log(drinkOrders.find((drinkorders) => drinkorders.id === 3).customerName;`

Comment: What IDE (editor) are you using? Most of them will highlight this problem for you (undefined variable and unused variable).

Answer (score 0):

.find() will return the object that satisfies the finder fb. You can access its properties like you usually would:

```
console.log(drinksOrders.find((drinkorders) => drinkorders.id === 3).customerName);
```